# one job pipeline requiring parallelism

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

My pipeline has one job but I get the message requiring hosted parallelism. I have not been able to create a single job pipeline without getting this message. Created pipeline having one job. Since there is no parallelism in the pipeline I expected  it to run.

Comment: What is the **exact** message you get, and when do you get it?

Comment: ##[error]No hosted parallelism has been purchased or granted. To request a free parallelism grant, please fill out the following form https://aka.ms/azpipelines-parallelism-request
Pool: Azure Pipelines
Image: windows-2019
Started: Yesterday at 12:56 PM
Duration: 1d 1h 36m

Job preparation parameters
3 queue time variables used

Comment: Is this for a public project?

Comment: Hi @nathan, is the answer below to submit a request to enable Microsoft-hosted pipelines helps you? If it helps, just a remind of [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft was having an issue with people signing up for Azure DevOps organizations and using the free pipeline capabilities to run crypto mining.

[Yes, really.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/change-in-azure-pipelines-grant-for-public-projects/)

As a result, projects may require you to submit a request to enable Microsoft-hosted pipelines. The error message is providing you with a link: https://aka.ms/azpipelines-parallelism-request